# On default fill One2many

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

So I'm trying to fill a One2many list by default. I've defined a basic field, read the "special commands" for One2many and Many2many's but it doesn't seem to work for some reason (no error message or whatsoever, just doesn't fill it)

My code:

```
@api.one
def _get_competitions(self):
    result = []
    values = {'name': 'test', 'xx_price': 550, 'xx_seats_left': 50, 'xx_attending': True}
    result.append((0, 0, values))
    return result

xx_competitions_attendee = fields.One2many('xx.competition.attendee', 'xx_event_id', string="Competitions", default=_get_competitions)
```

Reworked it a bit and now I'm just returning a search result and still the list doesn't get filled:

```
@api.model
def _get_competitions(self):
    return self.env['xx.competition.attendee'].search([('xx_event_id.id', '=', self._context.get('active_ids')[0])])

xx_competitions_attendee = fields.One2many('xx.competition.attendee', 'xx_event_id', string="Competitions", default=_get_competitions)
```

I've already set the Many2one relation in the other model, I didn't think it was of great importance that I should post it here, but to be sure:

```
class CompetitionAttendee(models.Model):
   _name = 'xx.competition.attendee'

   xx_event_id = fields.Many2one('event.event', string="Event")
```

Comment: Will you use the relation for that one2many or you only have to show it in a form?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE :**

```
@api.model
    def _get_competitions(self):
        result = []
        values = {'name': 'test', 'xx_price': 550, 'xx_seats_left': 50, 'xx_attending': True}
        result.append((0, 0, values))
        return result
```

In above case, you will get values in One2many list because you are passing values to "xx_competitions_attendee" field

```
@api.model
def _get_competitions(self):
    return self.env['xx.competition.attendee'].search([('xx_event_id.id', '=', self._context.get('active_ids')[0])])
```

Default method will call when you are going to create record so in context there is not any active_ids so dictionary will return None.

So you may have error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

**NOTE:**

> You just need to set many2one reference while you feel one2many
>   record. Because One2many field is managed by framework it self and
>   it's always being generated against the many2one reference and you
>   have not specify any Many2one reference there.

```
values = {'many2one_field' : many2one_ref, 'name': 'test', 'xx_price': 550, 'xx_seats_left': 50, 'xx_attending': True,}
```

You should try following,

```
@api.model
def _get_competitions(self):
    result = []
    values = {'name': 'test', 'xx_price': 550, 'xx_seats_left': 50, 'xx_attending': True}
    result.append((0, 0, values))
    return result
```

> You have decorated method with wrong decorator, to set default values
>   method must be decorated with `@api.model` (blank recordset) while
>   `@api.one` always require recordset to call method.

You may refer [Odoo Docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#module-openerp.api) to know more about method decorators.

Comment: I totally forgot about the decorator. I've now made a record in my model (from the One2many list). In my default method I just return a search result (debugged it and it contains records). So basically the same as I mentioned in the OP but the list just doesn't get filled. I'll add example code in OP

Comment: If possible please update question with model structure.

Comment: I have updated answer with the reason why records are not there in default One2many. Check it and if not working then please update model structure in your question.

Comment: The relationship was already there, just didn't thought it was important enough to post it but I've edited the OP to include it.